# `wrong number of arguments` when adding actioncable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I know, there're plenty "wrong number of arguments"-like issues, but mine is different because I'm trying to add a real-time functionality with action cable.

What exactly I want to accomplish is, as soon as a new item adeed, the items list should be updated automatically on another browser.

The app is deployed at 
http://rails5-catalog.herokuapp.com

https://catalog-tenzan.c9users.io/items

Github repo https://github.com/tenzan/rails-catalog

**I'm having error:**

[image]

When I tried adding `@` for `item` at `def self.broadcast(item)` I was getting another error ***formal argument cannot be an instance variable***.

**What I did:**

```
rails g channel items
```

**app/assets/javascripts/channels/items.coffee**

```
App.items = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ItemsChannel",

  received: (data) ->
    # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $('#items').append data.item
```

**app/channels/items_channel.rb**

```
class ItemsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def self.broadcast(item)
    broadcast.to item, item:
    ItemsController.render(partial: 'items/form', locals: {item: item})
  end

  def subscribed
    stream_for Item.last
  end
```

**app/controllers/items_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    ItemsChannel.broadcast(@item)
    redirect_to @item
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

Comment: I have not used action cable so my guess is, its because that you are broadcasting to a `new Object`, not a persisted one. And also all are subscribing to `Item.last` so I guess they wont receive the update unless you subscribe them to a more specific channel instance since you dont broadcast to that specific `Item` always

Comment: Yes, i don't see `@item.save` inside your `create` action. Is it how it works with action cable? I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time. Error was eliminated as per my comment below, but I'm now facing actioncable usage issue. Will update as soon as I find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues as far as I can tell.

1. Typo

   ```
   def self.broadcast(item)
     broadcast.to item, item:
   ```

What you're doing here is actually calling `broadcast` again. But without any arguments. That's what's causing the error message.
I believe you want to call the method `broadcast_to` instead (`_` vs `.`).

2. I also believe you have another typo: `item, item:`

This is the signature of [`broadcast_to(model, message)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/broadcasting.rb#L12), it expects a model and a message, your typo results in you passing whatever `ItemsController.render(partial: 'items/form', locals: {item: item})` returns to `broadcast_to`.

You probably want something like

```
broadcast_to item, title: 'New Item', body: "#{item.name} #{item.price}"
```

instead.

3. You're not saving your newly created item in the controller with:

   ```
   @item = Item.new(item_params)
   ```

You're only initialising an Item object in memory, in order to persist the new item, you want to either `@item.save` it or `Item.create(item_params)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have refactored as suggested. No more errors, but action cable feature not working yet... Going to read more about it.

Comment: Glad it helped, do you mind marking it? Since ActionCable not working is a different issue.